# Calculating price from selected options in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html code :

```
<select class="form-control B3 pricing" name="B3">
  <option data-price="0" data-cheap="0">0</option>
  <option data-price="20" data-cheap="30">1</option>
  <option data-price="40" data-cheap="60">2</option>        
  <option data-price="60" data-cheap="90">3</option>
  <option data-price="80" data-cheap="120">4</option>
  <option data-price="100" data-cheap="150">5</option>
</select>
```

My jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var cheap=false;
        $('.day1').on('change', function (e) {
            var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
            var valueSelected = optionSelected.val();
            if(valueSelected=="Saturday")
            {
                cheap=true;
                alert(cheap);                   
            }else{
                cheap=false;
                alert(cheap);
            }
        });
    $('.pricing').change(function(){
        var price = parseFloat($('.total').data('base-price'));
        $('.pricing').each(function(i, el) {
                if(cheap==false){
                    price += parseFloat($('option:selected', el).data('price'));
                }else{
                    price+= parseFloat($('option:selected').data('cheap'));
                }
        });            
        $('.total').val('$'+price.toFixed(2));
    }); 
});
```

I want that when the day is selected as Saturday the data-cheap has to be taken and when other days are selected data-price should be calculated. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I could see is you are not passing the context to the cheap query

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cheap = false;
    $('.day1').on('change', function (e) {
        cheap = $(this).val() == "Saturday";
    });
    $('.pricing').change(function () {
        var price = parseFloat($('.total').data('base-price')) || 0;
        $('.pricing').each(function (i, el) {
            price += parseFloat($('option:selected', el).data(cheap ? 'cheap' : 'price'));
            console.log('x', price)
            $('.total').val('$' + price.toFixed(2));
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oxwxwp6L/)

Comment: I implemented your code. But it still display NaN. Your code works as i wanted in the Fiddle link given by you. But it doesnt work in my code. Please help!

Comment: @SaranshSeth can you update the fiddle with your code to recreate the problem

Comment: $('option:selected', el).data('cheap') This variable is shown undefined in my code. I have the same code as yours.

Comment: can you change `.data('cheap') ` to `.attr('data-cheap') ` and try

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t3zL4jpm/ Here is my code. Please can you edit here what you are telling. Thanks!

Comment: When i changed it attr in console the first loop return undefined then the second loop hold the value. Why so?

Comment: @SaranshSeth http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oxwxwp6L/3/ - seems to be working - how to recreate the issue

Comment: @SaranshSeth also try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oxwxwp6L/4/ or - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oxwxwp6L/5/

Comment: Yes it works there. But why doesnt it work in my site?